# Nested select in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a problem with solving this variation on bounded-buffer problem in ADA (Im very new in ADA programming).

I have two tasks (lets call it A and B) that can write into buffer and one task that reads from buffer (C). Task A inserts two integers into buffer at the time and task B only one. Before reading data from buffer task C need to determine which task (A or B) last inserted data into buffer, and if its A then to read two last inserted integers, otherwise only one.

This is how Im trying to implement buffer task, and I wondering is this proper way of doing it:

```
task bbuffer is 
    N : constant Integer := 20;
    buffer : array(0..N-1) of Integer;
    pointer : Integer range 0..N-1;
    count : Integer range 0..N;
    flag : Integer range 0..1;

    begin
        loop
            select 
                when count < N =>
                    accept PutOne(v:in Integer) do
                        buffer((pointer+count) mod N) := v;
                        count:=count+1;
                    end Put;
            or
                when count < N-1 =>
                    accept PutTwo(v1:in Integer, v2:in Integer) do
                        buffer((pointer+count) mod N) := v1;
                        buffer((pointer+count+1) mod N) := v2;
                        count:=count+2;
                    end Put;
            or

            -- THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS. Reading from buffer.
            -- I first need to determine what to call between ReadOne and ReadTwo

                accept GetFlag(f:out Integer) do
                    f:=flag;
                end GetFlag;

                select
                    when count > 0 =>
                        accept GetOne(v:out Integer) do
                            v:=buffer(pointer);
                            pointer := (pointer + 1) mod N;
                            count := count + 1;
                        end GetOne; 
                or
                    when count > 1 =>
                        accept GetTwo(v1:out Integer, v2:out Integer)do
                            v1:=buffer(pointer);
                            v2:=buffer((pointer+1) mod N);
                            pointer := (pointer + 2) mod N;
                            count := count + 2;  
                        end GetTwo;
                end select;
           end select;
       end loop;
   end bbuffer;
```

Flag is set when A is writing into buffer and unset when B.

I would appreciate any help on this, thank you!

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the language is "Ada", not "ADA" (it's not an acronym, it's named after a person).

Comment: Is this Ada83? If not, you would probably be better off using a protected object for your buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all: In Ada, tasks have to be declared with a separate declaration and body.  The declaration declares all the entries that other tasks might want to call.  The body contains the code of the task, which is what you have above.  Your task declaration will look like:

```
task bbuffer is
    entry PutOne (v: in Integer);
    entry PutTwo (v1: in Integer; v2: in Integer);
    entry GetFlag (f: out Integer);
    entry GetOne (v: out Integer);
    entry GetTwo (v1: out Integer; v2: out Integer);   
end bbuffer;
```

and the body will start with

```
task body bbuffer is  -- note the keyword "body"!!
    N : constant integer := 20;
    -- and so on
```

Another issue: use a semicolon, not a comma, to separate parameters of an entry.  That applies both to the `entry` declarations above, and to the `accept` statements that occur in your body.  Finally, your `accept` statements for PutOne and PutTwo in the body have the wrong name on the `end` statement.  The compiler will not (ahem) accept that.

As far as the logic: It looks like it needs some serious rethinking.  If the intent is for C to read data in the same order that A or B writes it (i.e. a FIFO queue), then your statement that you want C to determine which task *last* inserted data into the buffer seems wrong.  Instead, you'll have to set up your buffer so that it keeps track of whether each buffer "element" has one integer (written by B) or two integers (written by A).  I'd probably use a record type:

```
type Buffer_Element is record
    Num_Integers : Integer range 1 .. 2;
    First_Int    : Integer;
    Second_Int   : Integer;  -- unused if Num_Integers=1  
end record;
Buffer : array (0 .. N - 1) of Buffer_Element;
```

Note that this means the number of integers in the buffer varies depending on how many PutOne's and PutTwo's are called.  I don't know if this is OK within your requirements.

The way you've arranged the nested `select` looks OK, as long as you can guarantee that C will always call GetOne or GetTwo after GetFlag returns.  Otherwise, bbuffer could stall and A and B could never put anything in the buffer ever again.  Also, the "accept GetFlag" should have `when count > 0` on it, because you want C to block if it calls GetFlag when the buffer is empty, I think.  In any event, I don't want to give you too many specific suggestions because it looks like the whole logic needs reworking.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to help me out.

My C++ implementation of this is based on using 'BufferElement' class for the elements of the buffer, but as I said, I am very new to Ada.

I agree that it need some rethinking, this is basically the first thing that came to my mind. But you hit some aspects of the problem that will sure help me out.

Comment: Using another type for 'BufferElement' seems to be the most logic way solving this.

And yes, I am aware of 'possible deadlock' in case of calling ReadOne/ReadTwo before GetFlag from C.

Comment: In a simple case like this, I don't think I'd even want three Get/Read entries.  Just `entry GetFlag (Flag : out Integer; Val1 : out Integer; Val2 : out Integer)`, where Val2 may or may not have valid data; or entry `GetElement (Element : out Buffer_Element)`; could be good enough.  Then you only have to worry about C blocking the task for one call, and deadlock wouldn't be as much of an issue.

Comment: Just one thing more, about tasks in Ada in general (considering my example):

After calling to GetFlag from task C, task bbuffer WILL EXPECT GetOne or GetTwo call, and will NOT proceed (into loop) until one of them is not called. Am I right?


EDIT: you're right. No need for three different calls for reading.

Comment: @TedK. Yes; in the outer select, if the last `accept` is the one that happens, then the statement after it (i.e. the inner `select`) will be executed before it loops back up to the next `select`.

Answer (score 3):

I think a more Ada-like way of handling this would be to declare a type used both for the buffer elements and for the value returned by `Get`; this way you sidestep the synchronisation issue with `GetFlag` vs `GetOne`/`GetTwo`, and you can use a plain bounded buffer in the implementation with no need to worry about counts and flags.

The element type might look like this:

```
type Element (Single_Value : Boolean := True) is record
   First : Integer;
   case Single_Value is
      when True =>
         null;
      when False =>
         Second : Integer;
   end case;
end record;
```

which is a discriminated record; an `Element` with `Single_Value` = `True` doesn't have a field `Second` (I supplied a default for `Single_Value` for good but deep reasons, which would be worth another question if you're interested).

The task spec might look like

```
task Bounded_Buffer is
   entry Put_One (V : Integer);
   entry Put_Two (V1, V2 : Integer);
   entry Get (Result : out Element);
end Bounded_Buffer;
```

and the body of `Put_One` might include

```
Buffer (N) := Element'(Single_Value => True, First => V);
```

while the body of `Put_Two` might include

```
Buffer (N) := Element'(Single_Value => False, First => V1, Second => V2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different variant of how to manage the 1 or 2 values problem - using a protected object for the buffer:

```
type Elements_In_Buffer is range 1 .. 2;
type Element_Array is array (Elements_In_Buffer range <>) of Values;
type Element (Length : Elements_In_Buffer := 1) is
   record
      Data : Element_Array (1 .. Length);
   end record;

protected Buffer is
   entry Put (A    : in     Values);
   entry Put (A, B : in     Values);
   entry Get (Item :    out Element);
end Buffer;
```

I'm not quite sure if I prefer the variant record or the record with an array element.

But the protected object is definitely preferable to a task for implementing a buffer.

Comment: And this is really a queue: so, if TedK can use Ada 2012, he could instantiate `Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues`.